# Changing an existing has_many relation to polymorphic in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I've got an existing has_many relation between two models - call them 'cars' and 'passengers' - with a few thousand 'passengers' belonging to a few hundred 'cards' in my production environment.  I'm adding another model, call it 'trains', and I want to change the existing has_many relation between cars and passengers to a polymorphic one relating each passenger to either a car or a train.

What should my migration look like?  I want to preserve the existing relations in my database when I migrate, so I'd rather do some table-renaming rather than dropping the one column to replace it with another.  Further, I want to be able to do it without opening up the server console and manually editing all the records, so I can just migrate the entire database in one fell swoop when I push my changes to production.  Any suggestions?

**TL;DR: How do I change an existing has_many relation to a polymorphic one with a new model?**

Comment: I'm having to do the same thing right now but for a Request model. I'll post my results

Comment: I ended up going with the solution below. Frictionless

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will have to write some migrations like

1. Add two columns to Passenger table.
   ->  rails g migration change_column_in_passenger
2. In migration file, write following code in up method

Code:

```
def up
  rename_column :passengers, :car_id, :transport_id
  add_column :passengers, :transport_type, :string
  Passenger.reset_column_information
  Passenger.update_all(:transport_type => "Car")
end

def down
  rename_column :passengers, :transport_id, :car_id
  remove_column :passengers, :transport_type
end
```

Hence this migration will update all current `Car` relation in `Passenger`.
   Also will allow train model to have a relation with `Passenger`.

Comment: How about also throwing in add_index :passengers, [:transport_id, :transport_type] ?

Comment: I went with @akshay's suggestion, which seems to be working.  What does the add_index syntax do?

Comment: Indexing helps in searching better. add_index applies mysql indexing on particular columns.